# SQL where greater than in groovy script

Tags: sql-server, groovy

The following groovy script does nothing:

```
def cmd = /sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER -d LocalDevelop10DB -Q "DELETE FROM T_TimeRegistration WHERE TimeRegLineNr > 36"/
cmd.execute()
```

While this groovy script works perfectly:

```
def cmd = /sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER -d LocalDevelop10DB -Q "DELETE FROM T_TimeRegistration WHERE TimeRegLineNr = 37"/
cmd.execute()
```

I want to use the (effects of) first script. It seems the '>' character is somehow not supported, I tried escaping it but no joy. What am I missing, can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: How did you try to escape the greater than symbol?

Comment: I have no pointers whatsoever on how to do this, but I tried \>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Groovy at all, but if you want to avoid the greater than symbol, you could use between:

```
DELETE FROM T_TimeRegistration 
WHERE TimeRegLineNr between 37 and 2147483647
```

2147483647 is maximum int value

Comment: Well thanks that works. I will wait if someone has a better answer but otherwise this will be my solution.

Comment: It is not really an answer to the actual problem, I still don't understand why I cannot use the greater than sign, but I can move forward with this solution so thanks for that Andrey.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error when your run the script.
Try to run the query (DELETE FROM T_TimeRegistration WHERE TimeRegLineNr > 36) from SSMS and see if it works, or see why it doesn't work.
Maybe you have some fk restrictions and one of rows is refered in other table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I run the query in SSMS it works. The response is 
(0 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)